# like '%' does not accept NULL value

Tags: sql, null

I have query that is build from user's inputs ( passed via html form). It looks like (simple example):

```
Select * From [table] Where [table].[column] like '<parameter>'
```

This parameter may be optional so if user left corresponding input field empty I pass **%**. It worked fine until I encountered NULL values. I understand that '%' match symbols not null, but i would like to consider NULL as empty string in this case.

What should I do? Change query (how?) or pass another symbol(s) when user left empty input?

Thanks.

**PS.** It's real problem from existing system and i know it's far from optimal solution, but i have to deal with it.

Comment: I hope you are using parameterized queries, as your code may very well be open to SQL Injection. See [boby tables](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: Where does the parameter come from? (@Oded: I guess that's what `'<parameter>'` was supposed to mean…)

Comment: @Tomalak - I hope you are right...

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You can use `coalesce` to  treat null like an empty string:

```
where COALESCE([table].[column],'') like '<parameter>'
```

On SQL Server, you can also use `IsNull`:

```
where IsNull([table].[column],'') like '<parameter>'
```

Comment: What about the case when an index is defined on [table].[column]?

Comment: On oracle (at least the version I'm using, 10.2), coalesce doesn't work with an empty string. I have to use `COALESCE([table].[column],' ')` to match fields.

Answer (score 8):

```
isnull([table].[column], '') like '%'
```

Works like a charm

Answer (score 3):

I think this might work:

```
Select * From [table] Where [table].[column] is null or [table].[column] like '<parameter>'
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, how about

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  [table] 
WHERE
  ([table].[column] like <parameter>) OR 
  (<parameter> = '%')
```

...so that when you pass '%', you get all the rows back, otherwise it works like you have it at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

How about..

```
Select * From [table] Where ISNULL([table].[column], '') like '<parameter>'
```

So this will take your actual column value, or if that's null an empty string and compare it against your parameter, assuming you're using MS SQL server..

Answer (score 1):

Make two statements! If the user passed no parameter user:

```
Select * From [table] Where [table].[column] like '%' or [table].[column] is null;
```

Comment: Surprisingly, `NULL` != `NULL` , you need to use the special operator `IS NULL`

Comment: Isn't that the same as `select * from [table]`?

Comment: Yes, but usually you'll have more where fields, and the % could be a parameter supplied by PHP, for example

Answer (score 1):

Based On [Index in Where Clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/771999/why-no-math-function-in-where-clause-in-ms-sql) Issue With This Approach

```
where COALESCE([table].[column],'') like '<parameter>'
```

Is :

If you have used an Index on your [column], because of the COALESCE function,SQL Server cant use your index,it means that you've wasted your index

AND

Issue With This Approach

```
Where [table].[column] like '%' or [table].[column] is null
```

Is :

If the [table].[column] is null then the code will be like this :

```
Where null like '%' or [table].[column] is null
```

and regardless of second part of Where clause ([table].[column] is null)
the result of evaluation will be UNKNOWN and the SQL Server filter that record out.

NULL OR True = UNKNOWN

NULL OR False = UNKNOWN

So this is the optimized and null included approach :

```
Select * From [table] 
 WHERE 
      CASE 
          WHEN [table].[column] IS NULL THEN 1 
          WHEN [table].[column] like '<parameter>' THEN 1 
          ELSE 0 
      END   =  1
```

Comment: This answer is just a lump of code, it seems very similar to another answer. Please explain why this is a good answer, how the code works and how it differs from the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Good day, use this solution, I think it's a mixture of solutions:

```
@parameter nvarchar (30)

if @parameter = ''
      Begin
          Set @parameter = '%'
      End

select * from [table] as t where ISNULL (t. [column], '') like '%' + @parameter + '%'
```

If you just want to start with the parameter, removes the first '%' and the plus sign

I hope you find it useful

Answer (score 0):

I wanted something similar, to actually be able to find '%' (all) including *null* or a specific value when input.

For Oracle `isnull` does not work and in my case `COALESCE` neither.

I Used this option in the where clause:

```
where decode(table1.field1,null,' ',table1.field1) like '%'
```

Hope it works for others.

Comment: `coalesce` works on Oracle. Your code is equivalent to `where coalesce(table1.field, ' ') like '%'`

Answer (score 0):

For SQLITE

```
SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE IFNULL([table].[column],'') like '<parameter>'
```