# TSQL if not null then

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this statement in my where clause:

```
(A.[subject] LIKE '%'+@meetingSubject+'%')
```

I only want this to be searched if `@meetingSubject` is not empty.

As of right now, its returning all records when `@meetingSubject` is null

How can I accomplish this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [like '%' does not accept NULL value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924400/like-does-not-accept-null-value)

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate since OP says it returns all records and it shouldn't.

Comment: That's very strange. You should get no rows at all when `@meetingSubject` is `NULL`, unless you have ANSI null handling turned off. Do you mean that there is a `null` in your front-end application code? If so, it's NOT being translated to `NULL` when stuffed into parameter `@meetingSubject`.

Comment: Please clarify if it's a NULL and you have a database option set to defeat normal ANSI NULL handling, or whether it's really an empty string.

Comment: If you only want it to be searched when provided, you need to remove the condition altogether - that is, you want dynamic SQL.  SQL Server in particular has problems with 'optional' parameters like this.

Answer (score 2):

The question says "empty" and not "NULL".  If the value were `NULL`, the expression would fail and no records would be returned.  That is not the behavior the OP describes.  Hence, I think you arelooking for:

```
(A.[subject] LIKE '%'+@meetingSubject+'%' AND @meetingSubject <> '')
```

Comment: THIS is the right answer. Obviously the `@meetingSubject` parameter is not set to `NULL` but an empty string `''`.

Comment: The question uses both empty and null. By the way, why not checking the parameter instead of the field for empty?

Comment: @PatrickHofman Okay, that's a good point about the parameter vs. the field.

Comment: I don't think the question is using null and empty.  It using both terms but I don't think it is using both.

Answer (score 1):

case also exclude an empty string not only when is NULL

```
(ISNULL(@meetingSubject, '') <> '' and A.[subject] LIKE '%'+@meetingSubject+'%')
```

Comment: This makes no sense. If `@meetingSubject` is `NULL`, it would return no rows, anyway, so the only part of your code actually doing something different is the check for no empty string.

Comment: @ErikE your right if option CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL is set to default. If not, concatenation return empty string. From another side interesting how the data looks like.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188795.aspx

This might do what you want:

```
 ( @meetingSubject IS NOT NULL and @meetingSubject != '' and A.[subject] LIKE '%'+@meetingSubject+'%')
```

Comment: Switch the conditions. It will make the execution faster.

Comment: Same issue using this code, it is returning all data when subject is empty.

Comment: This makes no sense. If `@meetingSubject` is `NULL`, it would return no rows, anyway, so the only part of your code actually doing something different is the check for no empty string.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a cleaner approach, though [Gordon Linoff answer would work as well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24127431/3699334/)

`A.[Subject] like '%' + NULLIF(@meetingSubject, '') + '%'`

Cleaner in the since of readability.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think @meetingSubject is null
I think @meetingSubject is ''
It is not the same in TSQL

That first @var = null; does NOT return found.

```
declare @var varchar(100)
declare @search varchar(100)
set @search = 'searchvaluesting'
set @var = null;
select '%' + @var + '%';
select 'found' where @search like '%' + @var + '%';  -- returns nothing
select 'found' where @search like '%' + @var + '%' and @var <> '';  -- returns nothing
set @var = '';
select '%' + @var + '%';
select 'found' where @search like '%' + @var + '%' and @var <> '';  -- returns nothing
set @var = '  ';
select '%' + @var + '%', LEN(@var);
select 'found' where @search like '%' + @var + '%' and @var <> '';  -- returns nothing
set @var = 'value';
select '%' + @var + '%';
select 'found' where @search like '%' + @var + '%' and @var <> '';  -- returns found
```