# Best way to handle NULL in MySQL logical subexpressions

Tags: mysql

I am not used to working with NULL and i am facing some problems. For example one would think that this query returns all customers:

```
SELECT * from customers WHERE ( job LIKE '%expert%' OR job NOT LIKE '%expert%' )
```

But reality is that it won't return customers with a NULL job.

That's an example. A more real world query could be:

```
SELECT * from customers WHERE NOT ( job LIKE '%expert%' )
```

And to work properly it could be rewritten like:

```
SELECT * from customers WHERE NOT ( job IS NOT NULL AND job LIKE '%expert%' )
```

What's the best way of dealing with this NULL in logical subexpressions? I am mainly a PHP programmer for small scripts (i'm not used to ORM or other frameworks).

Comment: Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924400/like-does-not-accept-null-value) out

Comment: do you **want** to return rows with a `null` job or do your **not** want to return them?

Comment: Yes, I want to return all the non-experts, even if they are null.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the proper results by using this query

`SELECT * from customers WHERE NOT ( job LIKE '%expert%' ) OR job IS NULL`

Answer (score 0):

I guess `COALESCE()` is quite handy in most cases.

My last example could be like:

```
SELECT * from customers WHERE NOT ( COALESCE(job,'') LIKE '%expert%' )
```

It replaces `job` with an empty string if it happened to be `NULL`.