# Is SQL LIKE NULL valid syntax for all database?

Tags: sql, rdbms, sql-like

I have a simple query (actual query will be more complicated. It is a dynamic query)

```
SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE @firstName IS NULL OR firstName LIKE @firstName
```

@firstName will be passed as

- NULL
- '%name%'

When @firstName passed as '%name%'. The query will work fine.

When @firstName passed as NULL. The query will be:

```
SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE NULL IS NULL OR firstName LIKE NULL

// This query is valid syntax on MSSQL and return all employees
// because NULL IS NULL evaluated as TRUE
// And firstName LIKE NULL evaluated as FALSE
```

**My question is**

Is **firstName LIKE NULL** valid on all SQL databases? and will it always be evaluated as FALSE?

I have checked this LIKE syntax https://www.w3schools.com/SQl/sql_like.asp

and this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx

But I didn't find my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `LIKE NULL` is valid in all RDBMS. `LIKE` is an operator followed by a string and a string can be null; so no problem.

Comparing a value to `NULL`, no matter what operator (`<`, `<=`, `=`, `<>`, `LIKE`, etc. - except for `IS` which is especially made to compare with `NULL`), results in `UNKNOWN`. `UNKNOWN` is not `TRUE`, so the condition is not met in case of `NULL`. And anyway, in case `@firstName` contains `NULL`, `@firstName IS NULL` evaluates to `TRUE`, so it doesn't even matter what `LIKE @firstName` results in then (because `@firstName IS NULL OR firstName LIKE @firstName` is `TRUE` when at least one of the two conditions is `TRUE`).

Comment: I tested LIKE NULL on Mssql, MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLite. They worked fine. But It failed on Oracle database.

Comment: *How* did it fail? It works just just fine for me in Oracle 11.2. And I actually doubt that any Oracle version would not handle this correctly. That would be a severe bug.

Comment: I used sqlfiddle. I just tested again. It seems that sqlfiddle Oracle is having problem so the query didn't work. I will accept this answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
LIKE NULL
```

is not a meaningful expression for RDBMs that support or implement the SQL 92 standard.

First off, NULL [going all the way back to C.J. Date] means "unknown", so nothing can be 'LIKE' unknown.

The only valid tests for NULL are "IS NULL" or "IS NOT NULL".

Comment: I agree LIKE NULL is not meaningful for RDBMS but is it valid syntax and will be evaluated as FALSE?

Comment: undefined / behaviour not defined in the SQL 92 standard.   MS SQL behaviour not consistent in other engines.

Comment: I need to test the query on some popular RDBMS. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This has been asked before. Here are a coulpe of good answers:

[like '%' does not accept NULL value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924400/like-does-not-accept-null-value)

[Behaviour of NOT LIKE with NULL values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22818070/behaviour-of-not-like-with-null-values)

If you are simply trying to check if value IS NULL- then make the syntax:

SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE firstName IS NULL

(NULL IS NULL will always return true- it is identical to "WHERE 1 = 1"). Hope this helps somewhat.